# Correct way to access proxy's owner in association extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

It looks like association extensions have changed quite a bit throughout Rails 3.x.

I need to access the proxy owner and the proxy target (i.e, the has_many object and the belongs_to object).

The most [recent documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) says To use `proxy_association.owner` and `proxy_association.target`. However, this throws an method missing. I found some older references (can't find them now), saying that `self.proxy_target` would work. However this only seems to work intermittently and isn't reliable between my local environment and production (strange... I know).

Does anybody know where I can find more definitive answer on how to access the owner and target from within an association extension using **Rails 3.0.10**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`proxy_association` is new in rails 3.1. The rails 3.0.x (and 2.x) equivalent is `proxy_owner` and `proxy_target`. However `proxy_target` returns the instance variable that caches the association if it has been loaded, i.e. if the association has not yet been loaded you'd get back `[]` for a collection association. Or in other words, given

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foos do
    def target_test
      proxy_target
    end
  end
end
```

then

```
bar = Bar.first
bar.foos.target_test #=> []
bar.foos.inspect
bar.foos.target_test #=> [#<Foo id: 1 ...>]
```

You can force the target to be loaded by calling `load_target` before calling `proxy_target`. That all set I'm not sure why this is important - if you call stuff on `self` it will be forwarded to the target for you

Comment: load_target did the trick! Not sure why calling methods on self didn't work. Thanks!